# Access ViewPager's Parent Fragment View in child fragment of Pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to access a parent Fragment views in a child fragment which is attached with a View Pager. Means Parent Fragment contains a View Pager and View Pager then have a Fragment, and I want to use Parent Fragment Views in current Fragment of Pager.

Parent Fragment---->(Contains)View Pager------>(Contains)Child Fragment. Child Fragment wants to use Parent Fragment multiple views. Please suggest any solution regarding the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YOUR TAG") or getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.YOURFRAGMENT)

Answer (score 23):

in your child fragment use:

```
ParentFragment frag = ((ParentFragment)this.getParentFragment());
```

and in your parent fragment you can store the references of your required views and use getter setter to access them, another solution is creating a listener interface. follow below link to find out how to implement:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for!

Comment: this is will return null in api <17

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method


Not Working

Comment: Kotlin version: `val parentFrag = parentFragment as ParentFragment` or use `as?` if it's possible this Fragment class might appear in different parent Fragment classes.

Answer (score 14):

Inside Parent Fragment

```
     ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager())
```

make sure it is getChildFragmentManager()

and inside the child fragment, to access anything from parent fragment

```
     ((ParentFragment)this.getParentFragment()).any_thing_inside_parent_fragment;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the below code.

```
        FloatingActionButton fab =  getParentFragment().getView().findViewById(R.id.menu_item);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to get a `sibling Fragment` using the `parent` so I tried to use `getParentFragment()` from the `child Fragment` and it was always returning `null`. So instead I just got the fragment from the `viewpagerAdapter` here's what I did to access a `sibling Fragment`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) container;
    BasePagerAdapter bpa = (BasePagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter();
    MySiblingFragment f = (MySiblingFragment) bpa.getItem(1); //I know the position of the fragment so I hardcoded it

}
```

hopes this will help someone.

Comment: Best solution brother.

Comment: we need access parent framgent from child not the opposite.

Answer (score -4):

I get the variable and view from activity using this

```
YourActivity activity = (YourActivity) getActivity();
activity.mVar = 1;
activity.textView.setText("Number "+activity.mVar);
```